# Face2 file for three.js

Tags: c#, asp.net, object, three.js

I have .obj file but in two face format,
so i want to use the three.min.js with the function face2,

so if any body have the older version of it then please appreciate for sharing.

or if there is any other alternative

Thanks,
Pratik

Comment: what do you mean two face format? .obj files have a specific format.

Comment: my .obj file format contain something like "f 9416/9416 9942/9942 9971/9971" this is just the one but in .obj file there are alot...if you want to see the .obj file then let me know i share you

Comment: due to these format I get the error message in objloader like "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'clone' of undefined"....I dont understand why but I am guessing it is due to face function in three.min.js file

Comment: no that is a valid obj format. your error is somewhere else. are you sure your libraries are all of the same version. If you are able to post the .obj it would be great.

Comment: it very big obj file...I can send you via email

Comment: or any other source where i can upload the file?

Comment: I think you should search google for your error in relation to three.js. I have found many references. I am sure you are using a function from a previous version of three.js. If you want create a jsfiddle with a much smaller obj file.